# Write program that reads numbers while negative number is not entered. Print maximum number among entered values as a result

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried to write like:

```
print "Enter numbers, stops when negative value is entered:"
numbers = [input('value: ') for i in range(10)]
while numbers<0:
```

but suddenly, I lose my mind, and don't know what to do next

the example is:

> Enter numbers, stops when negative value is entered:
>
> value: 5
>
> value: 9
>
> value: 2
>
> value: 4
>
> value: 8
>
> value: -1
>
> Maximum is 9

Comment: What happens if a user enters something that's not a number? Can they be > 9? What are you trying to do with that list comprehension?

Comment: You are misusing a list comprehension as a loop replacement

Comment: I had fun with this question by reinterpreting "a negative number" as `-1`. Result: `print('Maximum is {}'.format(max(iter(lambda:int(raw_input('Enter a number, or -1 to quit: ')), -1))))`. The point of this comment is that if you're more firm with your sentinel definitions, Python becomes very expressive.

Comment: @kojiro: Nice! I didn't know about that second use of `iter()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
print "Enter numbers, stops when negative value is entered:"
nums = []
while True: # infinite loop
    try: n = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) # raw_input returns a string, so convert to an integer
    except ValueError: 
        n = -1
        print "Not a number!"
    if n < 0: break # when n is negative, break out of the loop
    else: nums.append(n)
print "Maximum number: {}".format(max(nums))
```

Comment: Why do you need the `n > 0` check, if you've got the `n < 0` one?

Comment: `int()` will throw a `ValueError` if the input isn't an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something along these lines:

```
def get_number():
    num = 0
    while True: # Loop until they enter a number
        try:
            # Get a string input from the user and try converting to an int
            num = int(raw_input('value: '))
            break
         except ValueError:
            # They gave us something that's not an integer - catch it and keep trying
            "That's not a number!"

     # Done looping, return our number
     return num

print "Enter numbers, stops when negative value is entered:"
nums = []
num = get_number() # Initial number - they have to enter at least one (for sanity)
while num >= 0: # While we get positive numbers
    # We start with the append so the negative number doesn't end up in the list
    nums.append(num)
    num = get_number()

print "Max is: {}".format(max(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
# Show the startup message
print "Enter numbers, stops when negative value is entered:"

# This is the list of numbers
numbers = []

# Loop continuously
while True:
   
    try:
        # Get the input and make it an integer
        num = int(raw_input("value: "))
    
    # If a ValueError is raised, it means input wasn't a number
    except ValueError:

        # Jump back to the top of the loop
        continue

    # Check if the input is positive
    if num < 0:

        # If we have got here, it means input was bad (negative)
        # So, we break the loop
        break

    # If we have got here, it means input was good
    # So, we append it to the list
    numbers.append(num)

# Show the maximum number in the list
print "Maximum is", max(numbers)
```

Demo:

> Enter numbers, stops when negative value is entered:
>
> value: 5
>
> value: 9
>
> value: 2
>
> value: 4
>
> value: 8
>
> value: -1
>
> Maximum is 9